# Gradle user home not working in gradle.properties file

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I don't want to set environment variables,

So I defined gradle.user.home in the global `$USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, 
but it didn't work.

Windows 10

JDK 1.8

Gradle 4.10.3

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.6

Here is my gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.gradle.user.home=E:\\dev\\repository\\.gradle
# OR
gradle.user.home=E:\\dev\\repository\\.gradle
```

Comment: Why don't you add GRADLE_HOME to the environment variables of windows? Did you add  Gradle to Path variable?

Comment: What error do you get while running tasks?